# Is there any way to use arrays in a puppet module (not in template)?

Tags: configuration, puppet, hadoop

I want to use puppet to manage a hadoop cluster. On the machines we have several directories which must be created and set permissions.

But i'm unable to add array values for defined methods.

```
define hdfs_site( $dirs ) {
    file { $dirs:
        ensure => directory,
        owner => "hadoop",
        group => "hadoop",
        mode  => 755;
    }

    file {
        "/opt/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml":
            content => template("hdfs-site.xml.erb"),
            owner   => "root",
            group   => "root",
            mode    => 644;
    }
}

define hadoop_slave( $mem, $cpu, $dirs ) {
    hadoop_base {
        mem => $mem,
        cpu => $cpu,
    }

    hdfs_site {
        dirs => $dirs,
    }
}
```

`hadoop_base` is similar to `hdfs_site`.

**EDIT**

The error message was:

> Could not parse for environment production: All resource specifications require names; expected '%s' at /etc/puppet/modules/hadoop/manifests/init.pp:52

which is the `$dirs` line in `hadoop_slave`

Comment: I wanted to explain what is in `site.pp` but serverfault threw an exception :(

Comment: Please define how you being "unable to add array values for defined methods" manifests itself in form of error messages or unwanted side effects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the message tells you, any resource specification requires a name.

In your specific case the following snippet should work:

```
define hadoop_slave( $mem, $cpu, $dirs ) {
    hadoop_base { "${name}_hadoop_base":
        mem => $mem,
        cpu => $cpu,
    }

    hdfs_site { "${name}_hdfs_site":
        dirs => $dirs,
    }
}
```